# Case-insensitive Location

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy, visualsvn-server

I am using VisualSVN Server that installs an Apache server.

In the below example

```
    <Location /MyIISWebSite>
      ProxyPass https://my-domain.com:8443/MyIISWebSite
      ProxyPassReverse https://my-domain.com:8443/MyIISWebSite
    </Location>
```

how do I make the

```
    <Location /MyIISWebSite >
```

to be ***case insensitive*** 
in order to match ***all combinations*** (like myiiswebsite, MYIISWEBSITE, ...) ?

Answer (score 7):

Use LocationMatch with a case-insensitive regex modifier, like so:

```
<LocationMatch "(?i)/MyIISWebSite">
...
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: I tried this, but is not working. Is there a mod I should have included for this to work?

Comment: Hm, works in a VirtualHost container. No additional mods necessary, that I'm aware of. Docs here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch

Comment: How does the solution apply to a ProxyPass example? Could you provde a example?

Answer (score 3):

I've been using:

```
<LocationMatch "/(?i:mywebsite)">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</LocationMatch>
```

and that works on apache 2.2

Comment: Worked for me on Apache/2.4.7 :D

Comment: How does the solution apply to a ProxyPass example? Could you provde a example?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question. Just posting a solution which can be helpful for others.

I use ProxyPassMatch which is equivalent to ProxyPass but allows usage of regular expressions.

Refer [Apache HTTP Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxymatch)

Example :

ProxyPassMatch (?i)/abc http://mydomain.com/handle-all-variants-of-abc

This will match all combinations : (abc, abC, aBc, Abc, ABc, aBC, AbC, ABC)

Comment: How does the solution apply to ProxyPass? Could you provde a example?